# the function onReceive never called

Tags: android

I don't success to register or use my `broadCastReceiver`.

This is my code:

```
   public class ReciverChangeProgress extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        android.util.Log.e("ReciverChagne", "IReciver");
    }

}

public ReciverChangeProgress reciverChangeProgress;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.e("ReciverChange","onCreate");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_progress);
    progressBar= (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    Log.e("ReciverChange","setProgress");
    progressBar.setProgress(UploadService.lastPercent);
    IntentFilter intentFilter=new IntentFilter("commoshe");
    registerReceiver(reciverChangeProgress,intentFilter);
    android.util.Log.e("ReciverChagne", "register");
    sendBroadcast(new Intent("commoshe"));
    android.util.Log.e("ReciverChagne", "Use");

}
```

When I run the Activity this is the LogCat:

`ReciverChange, onCreate
ReciverChange, setProgresS
ReciverChange, regiseter
ReciverChange, use`

But the function onReceive never called.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: If that is the real code then you might want to initialize the "reciverChangeProgress" object before sending it to registerReceiver() method..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I success.

I forget to to this:

`reciverChangeProgress=new ReciverChangeProgress();`

We need to set the new object as new instance of our broadcaseReceiver.

Answer (score 0):

```
reciverChangeProgress=new ReciverChangeProgress();
```

***`onReceive()` is never called. Because BroadCast is never been send. You've just registered for receiving BroadCastReceiver***

***To Send BroadCast try these method using proper `IntentFilter`***

```
Intent intent = new Intent("commoshe");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Hope it may help you!